# make DISQUS load avatar picture instead of user picture in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, disqus

In user profiles I crated a field called Avatar and has a machine name of field_avatar

I was wondering if I could make DISQUS load the Avatar picture instead of the default Drupal user picture for comments.

Here is the default DISQUS code

```
        // Load the user's avatar.
    $user_picture_default = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    if (isset($account->picture) && !empty($account->picture) && is_numeric($account->picture) && $file = file_load($account->picture)) {
      $data['avatar'] = !empty($file->uri) ? $file->uri : NULL;
    }
    elseif (!empty($user_picture_default)) {
      $data['avatar'] = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    if (isset($data['avatar'])) {
      $data['avatar'] = file_create_url($data['avatar']);
    }
  }
  drupal_alter('disqus_user_data', $data);

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: are you using this module https://drupal.org/project/disqus

Comment: yes, I am using that module.